# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress TLS gateway to upstream services which are non-TLS or mTLS

Tags: .net, ssl, kubernetes, istio, nginx-ingress

I have a simple  example app in which the ui (vue.js) connects to a backing service api (.dotnet core).  Both are built into their own respective docker images and work fine either in Docker or Kubernetes, when TLS is not used. When deployed to K8S, the url mapping from the UI to the API is done via the kubernetes service mapping, ie. (VUE_APP_BASE_URL = http://api-svc/api)

If I deploy the nginx ingress without TLS enabled, the application works fine.  However, when TLS is applied for the INGRESS, the UI is no longer able to communicate with the API.  I have my dotnet app CORS configured to AllowAnyOrigin, AllowAnyMethod and AllowAnyHeader for testing purposes.

I have implemented ISTIO Service mesh to allow for mTLS thru the envoy proxy sidecars and placed the nginx ingress controller and the ui/api pods & services in namespaces with the istio-injection=enabled label.  This seems to eliminate the need to manually setup TLS between the ui pod/container and the api pod/container.

Nothing is returned from the request.  I am curious why the request goes from http to https in the request url as I indicated it should just be: http://api-svc/api.

[image]

This is an overview of the kubernetes deployment.

[image]

```
SVC and Ingress Yaml

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api-svc
  labels: 
    app: myapp
  namespace: test
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: myapp
---    
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ui-svc
  labels: 
    app: myapp
  namespace: test
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ui-ingress
  labels:
    app: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
  namespace: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.local
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: ui-svc
            port: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.local
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Am I approaching this correctly? If so, what am I missing?  (an annotation perhaps on the ingress?)  Or is there a better approach w/o having to deal with TLS between the services.

Thanks

Comment: If possible, please include your istio configuration

Comment: Didn't really change anything in the configuration.  Just used the default. istioctl install --set profile=default -y

Comment: Still, it would be good to see your ingressgateway configuration.

Comment: I was looking at the nginx ingress documentation.  I didn't supply any additional configuration such thru a config map and haven't added any additional annotations.  The nginx ingress was installed with a helm chart nginx-ingress-controller (7.6.21).

Comment: Try sending a request from Vue app pod, or another pod in the same namespace, with `curl -v`, so we can see DNS resolution and connection details. Please add the output to your original post.